# How to read logs elements to find 5 minute intervals

Tags: python, list, logging

If given a log displaying all `resource` request in a given 24hr window, expressed as `seconds`:

```
log = 
    ['10', 'user_9', 'resource_10'],
    ['123', 'user_5', 'resource_9'],
    ['234', 'user_1', 'resource_3'],
    ['299', 'user_2', 'resource_3'],
    ['594', 'user_1', 'resource_1'],
    ['10293', 'user_8', 'resource_12'],

# Expected return: 4 [resource_10, 9, 3, 3]
```

How would you traverse to find `max` # of resources opened in a 5 minute interval? (300 seconds)

I've tried to traverse the list and capture all elements `150 <= x <= 150` but that doesnt capture elements `<300 but >150` away from `x`.

Here's some psuedo-code to outline my thought process but I'm not quite sure how to proceed without saving each element and looping through the logs `n^2` times.

```
traverse through first element in logs (time) 
    assign element to currItem
    traverse through list again
        see if each element is with 300 above/below of currItem
            save elements
        rinse and repeat
```

Comment: `150 <= x <= 150` is equivalent to `x == 150`.

Comment: You only need to traverse the list once for O(n) time.

Comment: @ScottHunter is there a way to compare the value in a single traversal? This is what I can't figure out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` (if the resources are sorted by time):

```py
from itertools import groupby

log = [
    ["10", "user_9", "resource_10"],
    ["123", "user_5", "resource_9"],
    ["234", "user_1", "resource_3"],
    ["299", "user_2", "resource_3"],
    ["594", "user_1", "resource_1"],
    ["10293", "user_8", "resource_12"],
]

out = []
for _, g in groupby(log, lambda k: int(k[0]) // 300):
    g = list(g)
    if len(g) > len(out):
        out = [i for *_, i in g]

print(len(out), out)
```

Prints:

```
4 ['resource_10', 'resource_9', 'resource_3', 'resource_3']
```

---

EDIT: The above example finds 300-seconds windows based on second `0` (midnight). If you want to find 300-seconds windows based on first time in log:

```py
log = [
    ["250", "user_9", "resource_10"],
    ["275", "user_5", "resource_9"],
    ["300", "user_1", "resource_3"],
    ["325", "user_2", "resource_3"],
    ["350", "user_1", "resource_1"],
    ["375", "user_8", "resource_12"],
]

out = []
for _, g in groupby(log, lambda k: (int(k[0]) - int(log[0][0])) // 300):
    g = list(g)
    if len(g) > len(out):
        out = [i for *_, i in g]

print(len(out), out)
```

Prints:

```py
6 ['resource_10', 'resource_9', 'resource_3', 'resource_3', 'resource_1', 'resource_12']
```

P.S.: You can convert the seconds to integers first to speed-up the process.

---

EDIT 2: If you want to find *"dynamic"* 300-seconds windows:

```py
log = [
    ["0", "user_9", "resource_10"],
    ["890", "user_5", "resource_9"],
    ["900", "user_1", "resource_3"],
    ["910", "user_2", "resource_4"],
    ["1600", "user_2", "resource_5"],
]

log = [[int(subl[0]), *subl[1:]] for subl in log]

current_min = log[0][0]
groups = [[log[0][-1]]]

for subl in log[1:]:
    if subl[0] - current_min < 300:
        groups[-1].append(subl[-1])
    else:
        groups.append([subl[-1]])
        current_min = subl[0]

mx = max(groups, key=len)
print(len(mx), mx)
```

Prints:

```py
3 ['resource_9', 'resource_3', 'resource_4']
```

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a short explanation on what `groupby` is doing here? Is it simply dividing the list based on elements that are divisible by 300 and comparing the length of the corresponding resource list?

Comment: @WilliamMerritt Yes, `itertools.groupby` is grouping the `log` list by `lambda k: int(k[0]) // 300`. The `//` is integer-division (or floor-division), so `10//300` is `0`, `123//300` is `0` etc. so they belong to the same group. `594//300` is `1` - so it belongs to different group.

Comment: Hmmm...  If there were entries in the log for the times 250, 275, 300, 325, 350 & 375, this would report the largest group as being of size 4.  But all 6 fit into a 300 second window.

Comment: @ScottHunter Depends on the author, if he wants windows based on second `0` (midnight) or first second from the log. I edited my answer with option 2 too.

Comment: Dynamic solution seems to assume all timestamps are distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other answer I was able to come up with an alternate solution, without having to use `groupby` or `import` anything.

This basically stores then result on the floor division to a `dictionary` `key` and stores the resources associated as the `values`.

```
def iterLog(logs):
    if not logs: return [] # base case

    logs.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[0])) # sort logs

    resDict = {} # Dictionary to store results
    for time, user, resource in logs: 
        remain = int(time) // 300
        if remain in resDict: 
            resDict[remain].append(resource)
        else: 
            resDict[remain] = [resource]
    return resDict

#    resDict = {
#        0: ['resource_10', 'resource_9', 'resource_3', 'resource_3'], 
#        1: ['resource_1'], 
#        34: ['resource_12']
#    }
```

From there you would just have to find the list with the higher count.

Comment: Seems to assume all timestamps are distinct.